# SQL Server Using Se Variables As Column Names

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, concatenation

I'm new to SQL and I am wondering if it is possible to have a variable such as:
`@fundCount INT = 1` and then concatenate that variable into another which will be used as a column name eg. `@fundColumn VARCHAR = FUND_ + @fundCount  + _CODE`.

I would then like to create a loop:

```
FOR(@fundCount < 21){0 as @fundColumn}
```

The output would be like this:

```
FUND_1_CODE FUND_2_CODE FUND_3_CODE  .... FUND_21_CODE
```

With zeroes as the columns data.

Answer (score 0):

You would need dynamic SQL for that, you can read about it at

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Beware though, dynamic SQL is not recommended unless necessary due to some security risks (you can read about them on the website too).